# Google Container Engine Architecture

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was exploring the architecture of Google's IaaS/PaaS oferings, and I am confused as to how GKE (Google Container Engine) runs in Google data centers. From this article (http://www.wired.com/2012/07/google-compute-engine/) and also from some of the Google IO 2012 sessions, I gathered that GCE (Google Compute Engine) runs the provisioned VMs using KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine); these VMs run inside Google's cgroups-based containers (this allows Google to schedule user VMs the same way they schedule their existing container-based workloads; probably using Borg/Omega). Now how does Kubernetes figure into this, given that it makes you run Docker containers on GCE provisioned VMs, and not on bare metal? If my understanding is correct, then Kubernetes-scheduled Docker containers run inside KVM VMs which themselves run inside Google cgroups containers scheduled by Borg/Omega...

Also, how does Kubernetes networking fit into Google's existing GCE Andromeda software-defined networking?

I understand that this is a very low-level architectural question, but I feel understanding of the internals will ameliorate my understanding of how user workloads eventually run on bare metal. Also, I'm curious, if the whole running containers on VMs inside containers is necessary from a performance point of view? E.g. doesn't networking performance degrade by having multiple layers? Google mentions in its Borg paper (http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/43438.pdf) that they run their container-based workloads without a VM (they don't want to pay the "cost of virtualization"); I understand the logic of running public external workloads in VMs (better isolation, more familiar model, heteregeneous workloads, etc.), but with Kubernetes, can not our workloads be scheduled directly on bare metal, just like Google's own workloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run Kubernetes on both virtual and physical machines [see this link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/#bare-metal). Google's Cloud Platform only offers virtual machines as a service, and that is why Google Container Engine is built on top of virtual machines.
In Borg, containers allow arbitrary sizes, and they don't pay any resource penalties for odd-sized tasks.